# reboot on kernel panic and drac

Tags: kernel-panic, drac

Does anyone know if it is possible to have a DRAC5 make a screenshot of the console when Linux reboots (automatically) due to a kernel panic?

Our current system doesn't reboot automatically when it panics, so we can manually make a screenshot using the DRAC when it crashes.

However, I'd like to configure it so it will reboot automatically when a panic happens, but still be able to log the cause of the crash.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain about the Drac 5, but the iDrac 6 Enterprise version records every boot, and keeps the last 3 in memory so you can replay them. The express version does not though. Also, it records only the boot, so if you're looking for information that would be before that (which is, I assume, where you would see the kernel panic), I think you're out of luck.

In Windows, I can tell it not to automatically reboot, this way I can see the screen before I reboot it manually. Is there some equivalent in Linux?